# postgres: id auto-increment with millions of rows per day. is it bad?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

in my database i save million of rows per day in a table and i delete all the rows after 2 weeks because i don't need them anymore.

i was wondering if it's good or bad to add a primary key id auto increment or i will hit too high numbers.

the table contains only inserts anytime an user issues a command with columns like the id of the user, the timestamp and the command. so to add a primary key i guess i necessarily need to add an auto-increment that will soon become very very high.

should i avoid to add it considering the amount of inserts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not bad, unless it causes performance problems and you have proof that the auto increment is the source of those problems, which is unlikely.

Frankly, 1 million rows per day is peanuts. You'll be fine. If you expect your scenario to continue for more than 3 years, you should use `serial8` (64-bit) instead of `serial` (32-bit).

Answer (score 4):

The "auto-incrementing" functionality in Postgres is provided by the `serial` data types.  These are described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html).

If you are inserting millions of rows per day, then I would advise you to use `bigserial`.  You won't have to worry about overflow or resetting the value.

Comment: i have not understood if when the rows are deleted after 2 weeks, those value for the auto-incrementing are used again or not anymore

Comment: Autoincrement values are not used again.